# Using CountIf to identify duplicate values

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have a question and it concerns using `COUNTIF` using `VBA`, I want to identify the occurrence of not all the data set range but if I pass in a specific value.

Code that I have looked at is:

```
For n = 5 To 11
    If Application.CountIf(Range("CA2:CA7"), Range("C" & n)) > 1 Then
        If Application.CountIf(Range("CA2:CA7"), Range("C" & n)) > 1 Then
            Rng.Cells(i, 85).Value = "Stamp as a dulicate"
        End If
        
        
Next n
```

The code looks at a range and identified duplicates but how can I pass in an attribute for example `123456` and look for all the duplicated values under `123456`

This part I do not understand.

Comment: `duplicated values under 123456` Can you please explain what do you mean by "under"?

Comment: Hello Siddharth, for example if i pass in a value of 123456 and i wanted to know all the occurrences of 123456 in my data set, this is what i meant.

Comment: In my data set i have the values 123456, 123456, 1212,321456, 123456. I want to know all the occurrences of 123456 only

Comment: Ok and when you say `know all the occurrences` what do you mean? Get total count of duplicates or their cell addresses?

Comment: Hello Siddharth i don't need the count but if i am looking through a range of cells for example C2 to C11 I want to know where the occurrence is in a loop statement so when i come across the first occurrence i can mark it as found then the loop will move to the next occurrence and i can also mark it as found, keep on looping through the range of C2 to C11 until i have marked all the occurrences

Comment: One moment. posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

> Hello Siddharth i don't need the count but if i am looking through a range of cells for example C2 to C11 I want to know where the occurrence is in a loop statement so when i come across the first occurrence i can mark it as found then the loop will move to the next occurrence and i can also mark it as found, keep on looping through the range of C2 to C11 until i have marked all the occurrences – user14156733

Not sure which one you want but I am giving you two procedures. You can use one of them. The first one searches for all occurences. The second one also searches for all occurences but only if there is a duplicate.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindAllOccurances()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SearchText As Variant
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C11")
    SearchText = 123456
    
    For Each aCell In rng
        If aCell.Value2 = SearchText Then
            '~~> Do what you want here
            Debug.Print "Found in " & aCell.Address
        End If
    Next aCell
End Sub

Sub FindAllOccurancesOnlyIfDuplicate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim SearchText As Variant
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C11")
    SearchText = 123456
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, SearchText) > 1 Then
        For Each aCell In rng
            If aCell.Value2 = SearchText Then
                '~~> Do what you want here
                Debug.Print "Found in " & aCell.Address
            End If
        Next aCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much i will use them both

Comment: LOL ok. But for my curiosity which one did you want?

Comment: Thank you and I wanted to accept your answer and mark it as very much appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: `Thank you and I wanted to accept your answer and mark it as very much appreciated. Thank you so much – 
user14156733
 23 mins ago` Accepting answers is not mandatory but if you must know then you may want to see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)